# Python tkinter, making a quiz with randomly generated questions that reset after each submit

Tags: python, tkinter

My problem is that I'm trying to make a math quiz in tkinter which asks for a name, and then picks a question using the randint function. The person inputs an answer, clicks submit and the app responds to whether it was right or wrong.

The problem arises in that I then want the program to after it has been submitted clear the question and answer and come up with new ones 3 times over (each time adding to a score which is then shown at the end), however I can't seem to find a way to easily do this; I've currently been trying a while loop but it isn't working.

So my question is how would I make that part of the code loop 3 times over asking a different question each time?

My code thus far:

```
    from tkinter import*;from random import randint

class Tk_app(Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        super(Tk_app, self).__init__(root);self.grid();self.createElements()
    def nameElements(self):
        self.NmLbl = Label(self, text="Name:").grid(row=0)
        self.Name = Entry(self);self.Name.grid(row=0, column=1);self.score = int(0)
    def createElements(self):
        Frame.grid_forget(self)
        self.QNum = randint(1, 2)
        self.QEnt = Entry(self);self.QEnt.grid(row=1, column=1)
        if(self.QNum == 1):
            self.QLbl = Label(self, text="What is the air speed velocity of a flying swallow?").grid(row=1)
            self.a = "African or European?"
        elif(self.QNum == 2):
            self.QLbl = Label(self, text="What is your quest?").grid(row=1)
            self.a = "To find the holy grail."
        else:
            self.QLbl = Label(self, text="What is your favourite colour?").grid(row=1)
            self.a = "Green"
        def submit(self):
            FinNam = self.Name.get()
            Ans = self.QEnt.get()
            if(Ans == self.a):
                AnsLbl = Label(self, text = "Well done you got it right, "+FinNam).grid(row=2, column=1)
                self.score+=1
            else:
                AnsLbl = Label(self, text = "Sorry not this time, "+FinNam+" The answer was " + self.a).grid(row=2, column=1)
        self.SBut = Button(self, text="submit", command=lambda:submit(self)).grid(row=2)


root = Tk();root.title("Monty Questions")
app = Tk_app.nameElements(root)
fin = int(0)
while(fin<3):
    fin+=1
    app2 = Tk_app.createElements(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: don't define a variable and the `.grid()` it on the same line as it will return `Nonetype`. You have to position it on the next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to have a while loop outside of your app class.  When the program is running, it should have called `root.mainloop()` before the user interacts with it at all, and stay that way until it is finished. The general structure of this code is not correct.

In Tkinter I would only have this outside of the class definition:

```
root = Tk()
root.title("Monty Questions")
app = Tk_app()
root.mainloop()
```

And then you set up all of your tk widgets and whatnot in `init`:

```
class Tk_app(Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        Frame.__init__(root);
        self.grid();
        self.createElements()
        self.nameElements()
```

etc.

Finally, if you just define `submit()` as a member function of `Tk_app` instead of as a nested function definition like you have it, you don't need to use a lambda function to pass `self`. Just do:

```
class Tk_app():

    ... __init__ and other things...

    def createElements(self):
        ... some code ...
        self.SBut = Button(self, text="submit", command=self.submit ).grid(row=2)

    def submit(self, Event):
        ... submit code ...
```

The `Event` is necessary because not only will `submit` be passed `self`, as all member functions are, it also gets passed the event that triggered its call.

This might not get you all the way but will hopefully help structure your code in a way that will allow Tkinter to work properly. Check out examples, especially [this one](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-hello-again.htm), to see how to structure your code. Explore that site and you should get an idea of the vibe of Tkinter.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your help. I'll add and adjust my code and remember it in future.